# Java (Android studio) emailer

Tags: java, android, email

I'm currently working on an AI in android studio, and having a bit of an issue with emailing. Basically, I hit the "send" button and absolutely nothing happens. I've double checked the code that gets the email pass/address/to address and all the id's match up and have the correct methods. The method also matches the correct button id. However, it doesn't output an error, it doesn't send the email, as far as I can tell it does nothing. Thanks for any help.

```
 public void SendEmail(View view) {


        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IgnisEmailUser);
   final String User = username.getText().toString();
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IgnisEmailPass);
    final String Pass = password.getText().toString();
    final EditText toEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IgnisTheirEmail);
    final String ToEmail = toEmail.getText().toString();
    final EditText body = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IgnisEmailBody);
    final String Body = body.getText().toString();

    Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(User, Pass);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(User));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(ToEmail));
            message.setSubject("Sent from Ignis AI");
            message.setText(Body);

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout XML as requested:

```
<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/IgnisHomeInterface"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_column="0">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls" style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay" android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1022dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:editable="false"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="952dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ButtonSay"
        android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
        android:textColor="#b77c06"
        android:background="#b6b6b6"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="evaluateInput" />/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtInput"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dummy_button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dummy_button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dummy_button"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/IgnisName"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#b77c06" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/lblOutput"
        android:textColor="#b77c06"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="@string/IgnisOutput"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dummy_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="101dp"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:textColor="#b77c06"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/IgnisEmailerInterface">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/IgnisEmailUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Your email address:"
        android:id="@+id/lblEmailUser"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/IgnisEmailUser"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/IgnisEmailUser"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/IgnisEmailUser"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/IgnisEmailUser" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/IgnisEmailPass"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblEmailPass"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Your email pass:"
        android:id="@+id/lblEmailPass"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblEmailUser"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblEmailUser"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lblEmailUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblEmailUser"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblEmailUser" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Their email address:"
        android:id="@+id/lblTheirEmail"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblEmailPass"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblEmailPass"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lblEmailPass"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblEmailPass"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblEmailPass" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/IgnisTheirEmail"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblTheirEmail"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/IgnisEmailPass"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/IgnisEmailPass"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblTheirEmail" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Body:"
        android:id="@+id/lblEmailBody"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblTheirEmail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lblTheirEmail" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/IgnisEmailBody"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblEmailBody"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblEmailBody"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/SendEmail"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Return Home"
        android:id="@+id/EmailReturnHome"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SendEmail"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/SendEmail" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/SendEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/IgnisEmailBody"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/IgnisEmailBody" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
```

Comment: can you include your layout xml?

Comment: Alright, I appended my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not evaluated against the id of the button but against the onClick attribute. That button should be and and you can pick any id as you want to.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/SendEmail"
        android:onClick="SendEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/IgnisEmailBody"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/IgnisEmailBody" />
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a ton, forgot I had to add that. Just got android studio, I'm used to using action listeners.

Comment: That has nothing to do with android studio. It's android basics and If that answers your question please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Alright, now instead of doing nothing it crashes the program... And I can't accept for another 2 mins. And by new to android studio, I meant android in general. I've only programmed very basic programs before: I'm in an AP Java Course, but I took the textbook home and did it. However, it's a very simple course and didn't even cover more than very basic GUI and simple algorithims. I'm trying to learn some practical applications.

Comment: The question was about the listener does not fire, if you have any other concerns post it in another question

Comment: Yeah, I realized that about 5 secs after I said the error thing, hence why I edited it out. Anyway, thanks a lot, can't believe I forgot that.